# Is there a way to make this function smaller?

Tags: flash, function, if-statement

this is the code with the problem
a have a star animation when the score is X the animation plays until a specific frame
how to make this function smaller with less ifs?
as u can se the function is from 500 to 0.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, star);
function star(e:Event):void{
if (totalScore<= 500 && totalScore>490) {
    if(GAME.stars.currentFrame == 51){
    GAME.stars.stop();
    }
}
if (totalScore<= 490 && totalScore>480) {
    if(GAME.stars.currentFrame == 50){
    GAME.stars.stop();
    }
}
///...
    if (totalScore= 0 && totalScore>10) {
    if(GAME.stars.currentFrame == 1){
    GAME.stars.stop();
    }
}
}
```

thx!!!

Comment: The last if statement is a bit weird.. is that a typo?

Comment: `Math.floor((totalScore-1)/10)+2`

Comment: but isn't there a way to reduce the primary ifs to a single function?

Comment: the last is a typo btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pattern you posted, I'd write it like this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, star);
function star(e:Event):void{
    if (GAME.stars.currentFrame == (Math.ceil(totalScore / 10) + 1)) {
        GAME.stars.stop();
    }
}
```

However, as @putvande pointed out, the final `if` statement doesn't follow the pattern (and looks like it has a typo), so if it isn't meant to follow it you will need to handle that separately.

Comment: sorry about that i'll try this one and we shall see thx a lot man

Comment: but isn't there a way to reduce the primary ifs to a single function?

Comment: this exemple reduces the second if from the primary one

Comment: var totalScore:int = 0;

Comment: it only takes the value declared here my value changes when buttons are pressed how to make it take the changed value and not the value declared at the begining